# Need only date in field in a table, not full datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm reading in info from a database and I'm really just having a problem with how it is displayed/sorted. I want to read in a datetime but I only want to display the date and I want it sorted from now to future.

```
nextreview.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
```

This is what I have now but this includes the time but I dont need it and want it gone.

Had this before:

```
nextreview.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
```

and when reading it in...converting the string to display like I wanted

```
ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

which was perfect except when it came to sorting.

So any help on how to get it to display as "mm/dd/yyyy" but still be treated like a datetime?  using c# and asp.net for webpage

Here is the code for those that were interested http://pastebin.com/WQBUyrQT

Comment: Not to be any more specific, but it sounds like you want to preserve the format as the DateTime initially, sort, then display with the format string.  (Unless you can sort in the database query itself.)

Comment: The formatting of this question is atrocious. Take the time to write it out clearly, and format any example code.

Comment: No idea what you are asking for

Comment: What you mean by **how to merge the two into 1** ??

Comment: @david yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just redid the page and built the table in gridview rather than building it in the code...in the end it was just much easier..had to change a bit of the code...but it all turned out good..thanks for all the input

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do it in a two-step process:

1. Keep the data as `DateTimes` and sort them (you can use LINQ's `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`).
2. Now that the info is sorted, you can use the `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` method on each member to turn it into a "date"-only string. You can use LINQ's `Select` method to do this.

For instance:

```
var myData = // get info from DB;
var sortedData = myData.OrderBy(a => a.DateProperty);
var stringData = sortedData.Select(a => a.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

`stringData` is now an `IEnumerable<string>` which contains the formatted date values in ascending order.

Comment: this sounds good, just a little confused on how to implement...i posted my code if it helps..but this looks like it will do exactly what i need once i figure it out

Comment: Basically, you need to get yourself a collection of `DateTime`s from whatever info comes back from the database. Turn them into a `List<DateTime>`, `DateTime[]`, or anything that implements `IEnumerable<DateTime>` or has your `DateTime` value as a property. Then you can order the data by that value and print it out.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting is a function of *display*, not of *business logic*.  The formatting logic therefore *belongs in the UI*.

Since you've tagged this question `asp.net`, I would suggest that you investigate the [DataFormatString property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) (or, in xml, attribute).  I think the specific value you're looking for is `"{0:d}"`.

From your sample code, it looks like you'd add this code somewhere near the bottom of your `Page_Load()` handler:

```
((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[1]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"; //date hired column
((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[8]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"; //next review column
```

(and add whatever other columns have dates, of course!)

Comment: i understand what you want to do..unfortunately this table wasnt set up in the .aspx page..it gets called by a placeholder...so how do you define the dateformatstring property in the code behind page

Comment: @EddyWhitaker The trivial answer is `obj.DateFormatString = "{0:d}";`, but it's hard to give a more useful answer without seeing some sample code.

Comment: oh i posted it..actually a while ago...its the link to pastebin

Comment: @EddyWhitaker ah, I see, sorry I missed that. Answer updated.

Comment: ok..just got in...gonna try this..i'm actually glad you caught the date hired..totally missed that until the end of work yesterday

Comment: looks fine until i run it..i get this "Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: @EddyWhitaker hm, I am not sure when the Columns collection gets populated; I'm not very experienced with asp.net controls.  It sounds like you're calling the indexer when the collection is empty, which you could fix by figuring out a way of calling it after the collection is filled.  Or, there are fewer than 9 columns for some reason, which you could fix by adjusting the index number.  Probably your best bet would be to post a new question and attract the attention of an asp.net expert.

Comment: there are definitely enough coloumns..and i'm pretty sure its after the the columns collection is populated..but thanks for all the help

Comment: @EddyWhitaker you're welcome.  You can always check `gvEmployeeReview.Columns.Count` to see how many items it holds.  Also, try examining its contents in the debugger (look in the private members).

Answer (score 1):

Well there isn't a System.Date type, so unfortunately you have to make it work with System.DateTime. However this is not a new problem, and there are known solutions.

Maybe a little more info is needed; what exactly are you using to pull records out of the table, what are you using to hold those records, and how are you structuring the database query behind the retrieval?

The first thing you can do, if you don't care about the time element of the date/time value, is to truncate it as part of the DB query. The formula in T-SQL would look something like:

```
   SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(20), GetDate(), 101)) as Today
```

There are operations that would give you the same result without going to a string and back, and in SQL Server 2008 and better there is a Date type that you can cast to, but the above query is relatively concise and works for any SQL Server version from 2000 on.

Second, if you can't do that (say you're using a stored proc you can't change), there's a Date property available on System.DateTime that returns the value with the time component zeroed (so, for instance, `DateTime.Now.Date == DateTime.Today`). If you're using a sorting method that can accept a lambda, such as Linq's OrderBy() or List.Sort(), you can project that value without having to change it. Or if you NEVER want to deal with the value, just change it by going down the table and setting each field in the column to the value of its Date property. Just don't save these values back to the DB if someone else may care about the timestamp.

EDIT FROM COMMENT:

A System.DateTime will always have a time component. Datetimes in .NET are based on a single Int64 "Ticks" value. One "tick" ~= 100ns. All the properties you see that relate to time, like Hours, Minutes, Seconds, etc are calculated based on that Ticks value, as are the Year, Month and Day of the "date" component. For instance, the Seconds property would be calculated by starting with the Ticks value, taking the modulo as divided by the number of Ticks per minute (600 million), then dividing the result by the number of Ticks per second (10 million).

So, it is simply impossible to sever the concept of "date" and "time", because they are both stored in the same numeric value. The best you can do is to specify a DateTime with a number of Ticks that is evenly divisible by 864,000,000,000 (the number of Ticks in 24 hours), so that the time properties all evaluate to zero.

Comment: for that 1st part..converting .. wont the datetime property once it gets to c# add the time back..just as 0's...2nd part..i'm not using stored procedure, i posted my code..just inserted sql statement in the code..but for this particular problem..timestamp is not necessary at all