# Trying to cut off time in datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having some problems getting only a date to show in my table..

I got some help on a previous question, but ran into another problem. These are the things we have added:

```
((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[1]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"; //date hired column
((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[8]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"; //next review column
```

Here is the aspx page http://pastebin.com/DnH3wcAG
and here is the code behind page http://pastebin.com/yY2nbbEG
When I run it, I get:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>       Parameter name: index"    and its on this line "Line 158:        ((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[1]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}"; //date hired column"

Any help trying to fix this problem would be fantastic. I haven't had any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just redid the page and built the table in gridview rather than building it in the code...in the end it was just much easier..had to change a bit of the code...but it all turned out good..thanks for all the input

Answer (score 3):

As the exception says, you're accessing a member of a collection that is out of bounds. Probably `gvEmployeeReview.Columns[1]` does not exist. How many members are there in `gvEmployeeReview.Columns`?

Comment: **Answer** or another question? :D

Comment: well according to the count..i have nothing in the collection..but i dont understand how i can have data show up..and it not be in the collection..i'm probably doing something wrong..but not sure what

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with date formatting. Probably the error occurs while trying to access a column. Note the column indexes a zero-based. If you have `N` columns, the indexes range from `0` to `N-1`. Try to use the indexes `[0]` and `[7]` instead of `[1]` and `[8]`:

```
((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[0]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
((BoundField)gvEmployeeReview.Columns[7]).DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
```

This yields the actual number of columns

```
gvEmployeeReview.Columns.Count
```

---

UPDATE

I am not a web specialist; hovever, I just made a test with a `GridView` and I got the date formatting right immediately. I worked with an object data source like this:

1. Create a class with the desired properties. Add a static method returning a `List<T>` with some real or sample data

   ```
   public class Model
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
       public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public static List<Model> GetModels()
       {
           return new List<Model> {
               new Model{ BeginDate=DateTime.Now,
                          EndDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), ID=1, Name="test"},
               new Model{ BeginDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
                          EndDate=DateTime.Now.AddDays(12), ID=1, Name="test 2"}
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. Place a `GridView` on the page and open the tasks window with a click on the little `[>]` attached to upper right of the `GridView`.
3. In `Choose Data Source...` select `<New data source...>`.
4. In the `Data Source Configuration Wizard` windows that opens, select `Object` and then click `OK`. Then choose the `Model` class as business object and click `Next >`. Finally select `GetModels` on the `SELECT` tab and click finish.
5. After the last step of point 4 a dialog window open with the question `"Refresh Fields and Keys for 'GridView1'"`. Klick Yes. The designer automatically adds columns for every property of selected class and displays some sample data.
6. Now, click again on `[>]` and select `Edit Columns...`. Select a date column in lower left list. You will find the `DataFormatString` property in the properties window under section `Data`. Here you can enter `{0:d}`.

Comment: well according to the count..i have nothing in the collection..but i dont understand how i can have data show up..and it not be in the collection..i'm probably doing something wrong..but not sure what

Comment: If you try to set the format-string BEFORE you add data to your `GridView` with the `AutoGenerateColumns` property set, then it will not have columns yet!

Comment: i set autogenerate to false..but then my whole table disappeared ..tried the formatting string..still go error..but when i take the formatting string and autogen=false out..table works fine...minus the appearence of thedates

Comment: If `AutoGenerateColumns` is `true` the columns will be added automatically; however you will have to format the dates after having added the data.

Comment: ok then...what is the best way to do that with it being a datetime? i guess i could refer you to that particular question from yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014586/need-only-date-in-field-in-a-table-not-full-datetime

Comment: actually..let me ask you this..do you think it would be easier to just redo the page, and build the table in gridview...or do you think you may know of a way to change format it after having added data

Comment: I updated my answer with a quick `GridView` tutorial for data binding.

Comment: @EddyWhitaker When someone gives you a good answer, you can upvote or accept it.

Comment: @IlyaKogan yea, i know how it works...been out of town..1st day back today...so i'm just starting to read through everything.but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at your collection datasource, your attempting to read something that doesn't exist. Think of it like this: You have three buckets. Now I ask you what's in the fourth bucket? This error is you telling me I don't have a 4th bucket.

Comment: yea..i understood what the error meant..just wasnt sure why i was getting it..also i'm pretty sure a duck is in the fourth bucket